# Xmonad with two screens - how to get i3-like behavior?

Tags: window-manager, xmonad

I am trying to use XMonad with two screens. Each workspace spreads over the two screens, but I would like to have workspaces per screen, like in i3. How can I configure XMonad to behave like i3?